# Xamarin + Android: [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

New to Xamarin development (but have been doing native development for both iOS and Android for over ten years). Got this project inherited from third party and trying to compile and run, getting this error:

[image: malformed manifest]

Where do I look at possible resolution? I tried to remove all permissions from `AndroidManifest.xml` but that did nothing, error still persists.

Comment: Did you read the entire error? It does tell you that you are declaring duplicate permissions with different protection levels. You can check the manifest after a build in obj/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Cheesebaron thank you, that was one thing I did not know about Xamarin (location of `obj/android/AndroidManifest.xml`)